# using filters in traversal neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

How can I add filter to given traversal :

```
TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description()
                .breadthFirst()
                .relationships( RelTypes.KNOWS )
                .evaluator( Evaluators.excludeStartPosition()).evaluator(Evaluators.atDepth(1))
```

So that only nodes with property `Name == John` will be in the result ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Evaluator e = new Evaluator() {

            @Override
            public Evaluation evaluate(Path arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0.endNode().getProperty("Name").equals("John")){
                    return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                }else{
                    return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                }
            }
        };

        TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description()
                .breadthFirst()
                .relationships( RelTypes.KNOWS )
                .evaluator( Evaluators.excludeStartPosition()).evaluator(Evaluators.atDepth(1)).evaluator(e);

        return td.traverse(a);
```

Comment: getProperty() is very slow. Can I use something other? Thanks!